# URL rewrite URL name change .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Sorry if this has already been asked I had a read but I'm worried about making a mistake in my `.htaccess` file so wanted to make sure I was making the right changes.

So I have a url that looks like `www.example.com/folders/my-blog` and I want this URL to be `www.example.com/my-blog`. I have multiple different pages on here so I don't want everything in the `/folders` having the URL rewrote to just `/` I only want that one page which is `my-blog` having the rewrite on.

I've read about using `RedirectCond` and `RedirectRule` but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule, by using below rule it will only affect your my-blog page folders directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^my-blog$ folders/my-blog [L]
```

Comment: As in, this will only effect the url `www.example.com/folders/my-blog` and nothing else? even `www.example.com/folders/my-blog-201` won't be effected?

Comment: Yes as what i get from your question give it a try if you want for all links in folders mention in comments.

Comment: Yup thanks! It isn't working at the moment, my .htaccess file is in the root of my project. So do I need a beginning `/` before folders?

Comment: Put this line after `RewriteEngine on` this line - `RewriteBase /` and then try again.

Comment: Also, instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME` should it not be `HTTP_HOST`. Since `my-blog` doesn't actually exist I still want it to serve the contents from `/folders/my-blog` I just want the `url` to be smaller/cleaner

Answer (score 0):

With a rewriting rule you should have something like that :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put this in a `.htaccess` file, in your `folders/my-blog` folder.